# Does React Native styles support gradients?

Tags: react-native

I see that someone made this for it: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-linear-gradient

But is there support for it in RN itself? Something like

```
style = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundGradient: "vertical",
    backgroundGradientTop: "#333333",
    backgroundGradientBottom: "#666666"
});
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Not at the moment. You should use the library you linked; they recently added Android support and it is by one of the main contributors of react-native.

Comment: react-native-SVG (another widely accepted package) also has support for Linear Gradient - a good and easy implementation on creating one can be seen here https://medium.com/@ibrahimozdogan/adding-gradient-in-react-native-f75ddd02aea4

Answer (score 48):

Just export your gradient as **SVG** and use it using `react-native-svg` and when after you import your component set width and height and `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"`to scale an SVG gradient at your needs.

Comment: This answer deserves comment as well. Hundreds of developers use react-native-svg library and still installs more libraries with duplicated functional. I was scrolling down shockingly that no one mentioned it and thought that I could be the smartest‍♂️.

Comment: Agreed with @AlexShtromberg Smartest solution without the need for an additional library. Deserves much more upvotes.

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` oh wow. Amazing.

Comment: Based on that answer I created a simple to use component (see below answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/74182982/5309984

Answer (score 15):

First, run `npm install expo-linear-gradient --save`

You don't need to use an animated tag, but this is what I was using in my code.

inside `colors={[ put your gradient colors ]}`

then you can use something like this:

```
 import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
 import { Animated } from "react-native";

 <AnimatedLinearGradient
    colors={["rgba(255,255,255, 0)", "rgba(255,255,255, 1)"]}
    style={{ your styles go here }}/>

const AnimatedLinearGradient = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(LinearGradient);
```

Comment: Very nice!
To have 45 degree gradient - add props: `start={[0, 0]} end={[1, 1]} 
 location={[0.25, 0.4, 1]}` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46712777/1657101

Comment: You can wrap your component in it as in here:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good choice for gradients for both platforms iOS and Android:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

There are others approaches like expo, however react-native-linear-gradient have worked better for me.

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Sign in with Facebook
  </Text>
</LinearGradient>

// Later on in your styles..
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 11):

A little late to the party but the best solution IMO is using SVG gradient with `react-native-svg` which is included in most projects.

Here is a **few lines versatile component** that I use whenever I need a gradient:

### Simple SVG Linear Gradient Component

```js
import { View, StyleSheet, ViewProps, DimensionValue } from 'react-native'
import Svg, { Defs, Rect, LinearGradient, Stop } from 'react-native-svg'

type GradientProps = { fromColor: string, toColor: string, children?: any, height?: DimensionValue, opacityColor1?: number, opacityColor2?: number } & ViewProps

function Gradient({ children, fromColor, toColor, height = '100%', opacityColor1 = 1, opacityColor2 = 1, ...otherViewProps }: GradientProps) {
    const gradientUniqueId = `grad${fromColor}+${toColor}`.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '')
    return <>
        <View style={[{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, height, zIndex: -1, top: 0, left: 0 }, otherViewProps.style]} {...otherViewProps}>
            <Svg height='100%' width="100%" style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
                <Defs>
                    <LinearGradient id={gradientUniqueId} x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                        <Stop offset="0" stopColor={fromColor} stopOpacity={opacityColor1} />
                        <Stop offset="1" stopColor={toColor} stopOpacity={opacityColor2} />
                    </LinearGradient>
                </Defs>
                <Rect width="100%" height="100%" fill={`url(#${gradientUniqueId})`} />
            </Svg>
        </View>
        {children}
    </>
};

export default Gradient
```

**[See those example usages on snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@topkat/svg-linear-gradient-universal-component)**

Comment: This is so cursed and it works perfectly

Comment: For anyone that may run into a type error, height now takes a DimensionValue instead of a number or string. Just replace the type with `height?: DimensionValue | undefined,`

Answer (score 6):

**EXPO?** Well, use this method **Linear Gradient** in React Native using EXPO. ***(Updated Nov. 2021)***

No Pod Installs, No Errors, No additional linked files.

```
expo install expo-linear-gradient
```

Then

```
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

<View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient
        // Background Linear Gradient
        colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.8)', 'transparent']}
        style={styles.background}
      />
      <LinearGradient
        // Button Linear Gradient
        colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
        style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Sign in with Facebook</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
```

Full Link here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/

Answer (score 5):

Here is a production ready pure JavaScript solution:

```
<View styles={{backgroundColor: `the main color you want`}}>
    <Image source={`A white to transparent gradient png`}>
</View>
```

Here is the source code of a npm package using this solution:
https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-smooth-slider/blob/0f18a8bf02e2d436503b9a8ba241440247ef1c44/src/Slider.js#L329

Here is the gradient palette screenshot of saturation and brightness using this npm package:
https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-slider-color-picker

[image: react-native-slider-color-picker]

Answer (score 4):

React Native hasn't provided the gradient color yet. But still, you can do it with a NPM package called `react-native-linear-gradient` or you can  [click here for more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient)

1. `npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save`
2. use `import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';` in your application file
3. `<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}> <Text> Your Text Here </Text> </LinearGradient>`

Answer (score 3):

Looking for a similar solution I just came across this brand new tutorial, which lets you bridge a Swift gradient background (https://github.com/soffes/GradientView) library while walking through every step to get a working React component.

It is a step-by-step tutorial, allowing you to build your own component by bridging the swift and objective-c component into a usable React Native component, which overrides the standard View component and allows you to define a gradient like the following:

```
 <LinearGradient 
   style={styles.gradient} 
   locations={[0, 1.0]} 
   colors={['#5ED2A0', '#339CB1']}
 />
```

You can find the tutorial here: http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/11/28/react-native-how-to-bridge-a-swift-view/

Comment: It's best to include as much from the linked site as possible in your answer. As it stands it's likely to be deleted as a "link-only" answer. Have a look at the FAQ for "how to give a good answer". Cheers.