# Convert CSS gradient to Expo's Linear Gradient?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a CSS gradient as -

`background-image: linear-gradient(-140deg, #93C6F9 25%, #97B4FA 40%, #A768FE 100%);`

I want to convert it to [Expo](https://expo.io)'s [Linear Gradient](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient.html)

I tried the following solution -

```
<LinearGradient
      colors={['#93C6F9', '#97B4FA', '#A768FE']}
      start={[0.25, 0.4, 1]}
      style={styles.gradient}
    >
    <Text>ABC</Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

But the result is a bit different. I guess it has to do with `-140deg` somehow. How to do it ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `location` prop & reached a little close with

```
<LinearGradient
      colors={['#93C6F9', '#97B4FA', '#A768FE']}
      start={[0, 0]}
      end={[1, 1]}
      location={[0.25, 0.4, 1]}
      style={styles.gradient}
    >
      <Text>ABC</Text>
    </LinearGradient>
```

Comment: something worth noting is that you can use values greater than `1` for the `start` and `end` since those are percentages from left and top. for example, in order to achieve something from the browsers like `linear-gradient: (231deg, #2c8262, #065a82)` i did:

```
    <LinearGradient
        colors={['#2c8262', '#065a82']}
        start={[1, 0]}
        end={[0, 2.31]}
        ...
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding the following:

```
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['#93C6F9', '#97B4FA', '#A768FE']}
          start={[0, 0]}
          end={[1, 0]}
          <Text>
            ABC
          </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
```

You can see a [live example here](https://snack.expo.io/H1kcGWp2Z)

And a [Codepen of the gradient](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXJYvz)

Comment: Naah I want gradient from `top-left` to `bottom-right`. Urs is `left` to `right` I just tried

Comment: I think I was able to accomplish that by doing:
`start={[0, 1]}
end={[1, 0]}`

Let me double check though

Comment: `start={[0, 1]} end={[1, 0]}` is much closer. I have to just rotate it upside down. The pink must come down. `start={[0, 0]} end={[1, 1]}` does the trick.

Comment: I was able to do it like so:
`colors={['#A768FE', '#97B4FA', '#93C6F9']}
start={[0, 0]}
end={[1, 1]}`

Comment: I was doing it in Sketch so wasn't quite getting it. Thanks Gurgen 

Comment: My pleasure @AkshayKadam